# Adding Javascript to button in Click funnels for AdRolls

Tags: javascript

I am hoping someone can help me.  I am creating a funnel in clickfunnels and am using retargeting with AdRolls. I set up 2 event tracking audiences and need to add javascript to 2 buttons.  They won't tell me how to do it, but I do know we have to put the javascript in external files and then call it (can I put both event pixels in that file or do they have to be separate?).  The event pixel should be triggered through the onClick function of the button on the page(s) where the event occurs.

This is the code for the pixel...so i'd have to create 2 and change the ID number in both:

```
    try{
        __adroll.record_user({"adroll_segments": "25c14f39"})    
    } catch(err) {}
```

And the first button ID Selector is: #tmp_button-90712-129 and the 2nd one is: #tmp_button-90712 . Both are default names for the buttons.  Can someone help me?  Thank you sooooo much!!